# TestCafe takeElementScreenshot behaviour changed - how do I get the old behaviour

Tags: testing, overflow, screenshot, e2e-testing, testcafe

I upgraded from Testcafe 1.6.0 to 2.0.1.

I noticed there are differences in how TestCafe takes screenshots.

This is a screenshot from 1.6.0:
[image]

This is a screenshot taken with 2.0.1:
[image]

This is how it actually looks:
[image]

As you can see in 1.6.0 and in the original the "Q" looks more like an "O" because it is cropped - like other letters. `overflow: hidden` is set on the element.

It makes sense. This is the actual box of the screenshottet element:
[image]

The actual text is in a div element inside the screenshottet element:
[image]

It seems like in 2.0.1 it disables `overflow: hidden` on the screenshottet element to take the screenshot.

Is there a way to re-enable the old behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe published a new version - `2.1.0-rc.1` with a fix for [the issue with screenshosts](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/7054). Please update `testcafe` and check the issue again. If it doesn't help, create a simple sample with the following template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml

Comment: Unfortunately 2.1.0 does not resolve the issue. I created a Bug Report: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7380